# Changing text in my woocommerce cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need some help with changing the text in my cart page. I'm using a theme called ecommerce gem and I want to change some text in my cart total. At the moment it says shipping and I need to change it to "verzending". I used FTP to make a new map in my theme and copied cart-total.php to edit it but it doesn't work. I tried to goolge but i couldn't really find anything that was for just changing text. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: Plese edit your answer to include links to the theme, or samples of the code and what you tried to edit in the PHP page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a translation related issue. I suggest you look into Poedit or use a plug-in such as Loco Translate to handle translations.

Comment: Thank you for your quick respond. i just downloaded Loco Translate and it says that most of my webpage is already dutch. I checked under woocommerce because thats where the cart pages are at. i changed shipping to "verzending" but it doesnt change it.

Comment: You can use Loco Translate to search for a word or sentence to translate. This should show you all strings containing the word 'shipping'. Note that it could also be in your theme, instead of WooCommerce.